# What is the difference between floral primordia and floral buds?

Tags: botany, terminology, development

As we know an axillary bud differentiates to form a floral bud, but what is a floral primodium?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I made some changes in your wording — please [edit] if you think that I've changed your meaning. Please note that we encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Finally, please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 2):

A [primordium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primordium) (plural: primordia) is the first recognizable manifestation of a biological structure. In the case of a flower this will be a small meristematic bump typically at the periphery of a [shoot apical meristem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meristem#Shoot_apical_meristems).

In contrast, a flower [bud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bud) is generally used to describe the entire structure including the meristem and any associated structures (such as bracts) that can develop into a flower. This structure often goes through a period of dormancy.

Another way of saying this is that, in the context of a flower, a primordium is a group of meristematic cells that has not yet formed any lateral structures, while a bud contains a meristem and its associated lateral structures. Note however, that I believe I've seen bud used as a synonym for primodium in some cases.

Another difference is that primordia are (usually) microscopic structures, while buds are (usually) macroscopic (visible to the unaided eye) structures.